# Selenium not able to click on Get Data button on using Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am scraping data from this website . The element is below and geckodriver

```
<img class="getdata-button" style="float:right;" src="/common/images/btn-get-data.gif" id="get" onclick="document.getElementById('submitMe').click()">
```

but can't get selenium to click it tried even xpath, id but not luck
is there any fix or work around to get it done?

Comment: Could also be you are going to fast for selenium. There are commands to help you with this. See the [doc](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To click on the element <kbd>Get Data</kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img.getdata-button#get").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@class='getdata-button' and @id='get']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img.getdata-button#get"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@class='getdata-button' and @id='get']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Sorry but its not working, please have a look at my code which  i have update in my question. Do fix my code if possibe

Answer (score -1):

You should probably try by id

```
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'get').click()
```