# Unable to locate element 'username' while logging in Instagram with Selenium hosted on Heroku

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, instagram

I have a problem with a headless mode of Selenium while making log in with Instagram. I have found a default web code snippet for Selenium headless mode, but it does not work to find a particular element on webpage (like username in Instagram main page). The code works fine locally on my pc, but when it is deployed on Heroku, it shows the error. The logs of error are below the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random as rd
import os
import schedule


def job():
  try:

    user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.96 Safari/537.36"

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.headless = True
    options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
    options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
    options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
    options.add_argument('--allow-running-insecure-content')
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--proxy-server='direct://'")
    options.add_argument("--proxy-bypass-list=*")
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
    options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.binary_location = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BINARY")

    CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = os.environ.get("CHROMEDRIVER_PATH")
    wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH,chrome_options=options)
    
    wd.get('https://instagram.com')
    time.sleep(rd.uniform(9,11))

    username = os.environ.get("INSTAGRAM_USER")
    password = os.environ.get("INSTAGRAM_PASSWORD")

    time.sleep(rd.uniform(2.5,3.5))
    wd.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(username)
    time.sleep(rd.uniform(0.95,1.45))
    wd.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password + Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(rd.uniform(6,8))

    wd.get('https://instagram.com')
    time.sleep(rd.uniform(2.5,3.5))
    print("SUCCESS")

    wd.quit()
  except Exception as e:
    print(e)


schedule.every(3).minutes.do(job)


while True:
  schedule.run_pending()
  time.sleep(10)
```

Error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="username"]"} 
(Session info: headless chrome=88.0.4324.96)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a character sequence within the *username* field on [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/) you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']").send_keys("Artem")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']").send_keys("Artem")
  ```

---

However, the *`username`* field on [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/) is a [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) enabled element, so ideally, to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']"))).send_keys("Artem")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']"))).send_keys("Artem")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: instagram_username]

Comment: Thanks, you have suggested 4 options, the last of them with WebDriverWait and XPath has worked for me.)

Comment: @Artem Yeah, I guess I have properly explained why the first two options may fail :)