# atom 1.54 can't fetch xpath from the browser (selenium webdriver with Firefox)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://pbx.voxbaysolutions.com/#/page/signin')

browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@ng-model="user.name"]').send_keys('thj')
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "voxbay_automate.py", line 8, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@ng-model="user.name"]').send_keys('thj')
  File "C:\Users\theju\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webd
river\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\theju\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webd
river\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\theju\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webd
river\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\theju\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\selenium\webd
river\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //input[@ng-model="user.name"]
```

fetching element

```html
<input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" placeholder="User email" required="" tabindex="0" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for the webelement to load before sending keys:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//input[@ng-model="user.name"]'))).send_keys('thj')
```

These imports are required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the `<input>` element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[name='name'][ng-model='user.name']").send_keys('thj')
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@name='name' and @ng-model='user.name']").send_keys('thj')
  ```

---

However the desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, so to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[name='name'][ng-model='user.name']"))).send_keys('thj')
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@name='name' and @ng-model='user.name']"))).send_keys('thj')
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```