# Selenium parsing https://myip.ms

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Writing a parser for https://myip.ms I can't register. I wrote that the parser would open the registration window, but I can't enter any data, an error occurs **selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://myip.ms/#a")

button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="fixed_width_page"]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div[2]/span[2]/a[1]')
if len(button) > 0:
    button[0].click()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
print('Работает')

login = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[2]/div/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/span/input')
print('Работает 2')
time.sleep(10)

driver.implicitly_wait(50)
print(login)
if len(login) > 0:
    print('tut')
login.send_keys('фвыфы')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the *Email* field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://myip.ms/#a")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Login"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@aria-describedby='uidialog']//input[@id='email' and @name='email']"))).send_keys("Коля Нарушев")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: myip]