# Which locators should I use in order to login to website with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to login to the website. But I couldn't fill username and then password. I am stucked on the step filling in a username. I assume that I am picking the wrong class name, but I don't know for sure. I would appreciate your help.

my code:

```
#
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
   from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

   driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

   url = "https://portal.spryngsms.com/login?redirect=%2F"
   username = "cosmos"
   password = "1234"

   driver.get(url) 

   driver.find_element_by_class_name('form__input-wrapper tw-mb-16 ').send_keys(username)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the `<input>` field you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://portal.spryngsms.com/login?redirect=%2F')
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.form__inputs div.v-input__control input[type=text]").send_keys("cosmos")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://portal.spryngsms.com/login?redirect=%2F')
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Gebruikersnaam']//following::div[1]//input").send_keys("cosmos")
  ```

---

Ideally, to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://portal.spryngsms.com/login?redirect=%2F')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.form__inputs div.v-input__control input[type=text]"))).send_keys("cosmos")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get('https://portal.spryngsms.com/login?redirect=%2F')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Gebruikersnaam']//following::div[1]//input"))).send_keys("cosmos")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: spryngsms]

Answer (score 1):

First thing `find_element_by_class_name()` accepts single class name Only not multiple class names.

Second thing you need to interact with `input` element NOT the parent `div` element.

Instead of `class name` you should use `css selector` to identify the **input** element.

For Username:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".form__input-wrapper input[type='text']").send_keys(username)
```

For password :

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".form__input-wrapper input[type='password']").send_keys(password)
```

Comment: You can use it for multiple class by changing space with dot as it uses css under the hood in python

Comment: @PDHide : Yes It does. But the current scenario if user wants parent tag as well child tag for identifying the element css selector would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Use below xpath locators,we are checking the tag input and the value of type attribute:

```
 //input[@type="password"]

//input[@type="input"]
```

you can use xpath as

```
//tag[@attribute=value]
```

and css as

```
tag[attribute=value]
```