# Trying to select an input box through selenium python but the 'id' in the element changes every time I reload the page

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

HTML:

```
<input id="4432e17d-eed6-4620-9bb4-d75ffbd321fa" type="email" placeholder="Email address" value="" name="emailAddress" data-componentname="emailAddress" autocomplete="email" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">
```

Refreshed:

```
<input id="4a463943-7f58-42ea-9317-ba9f9518811e" type="email" placeholder="Email address" value="" name="emailAddress" data-componentname="emailAddress" autocomplete="email" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false">
```

How can I select this element without using ID.

I've tried by XPATH and CSS SELECTOR both haven't worked.
Full XPATH:

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[3]/div[5]/form/div[1]/input
```

XPATH:

```
//*[@id="4a463943-7f58-42ea-9317-ba9f9518811e" except the ID changes.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the *Email address* field you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='emailAddress'][data-componentname='emailAddress']").send_keys("sebtheoo@stackoverflow.com")
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='emailAddress' and @data-componentname='emailAddress']").send_keys("sebtheoo@stackoverflow.com")
  ```

The desired element is a dynamic element, so ideally, to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='emailAddress'][data-componentname='emailAddress']"))).send_keys("sebtheoo@stackoverflow.com")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='emailAddress' and @data-componentname='emailAddress']"))).send_keys("sebtheoo@stackoverflow.com")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot this has worked really well.

Comment: How can I access an element by it's what's contained in the <span>

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting element by Tag name

```
input_box = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('tag_name_of_input_box')
```

or
since it has a name attribute so you can try that as well

```
input_box = driver.find_element_by_name('emailAddress')
```

or as it also has a place holder so even you can combine the xpath with placeholder

```
input_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('"//input[@placeholder='Email address']"')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for tags that don't change. For example, in both the data, **name** is not changing. Hence you can move ahead with that.

To access element using **name** tag, try this [syntax](https://www.lambdatest.com/blog/locators-in-selenium-webdriver-with-examples/#testid2):

```
driver.findElement(By.name("emailAddress"));
```