# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click' using find_element(By.Xpath) Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, attributeerror, selenium4, findelement

There was a change to the `find_element_by_xpath()` to `find_element(By.Xpath)` and now the click is not working.

Code trials:

```
search_btn = self.driver.find_elements(
    By.XPATH, "//*[@id='viewContainer']/app-listing-container/app-search-container/app-search-form-container/form/div[3]/button[2]").click()
time.sleep(4)
search_btn.click()
time.sleep(5)
```

Error:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52534/devtools/browser/5aafde31-7b7e-456f-9639-cdfa2bb70678
[16904:17532:0211/180317.139:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(227)] START: ReportBluetoothAvailability(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[16904:17532:0211/180317.140:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] END: ReportBluetoothAvailability()
[16904:17532:0211/180317.140:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(235)] START: GetDefaultBrowser(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[16904:12228:0211/180317.149:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:03:17.148] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[16904:12228:0211/180317.157:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:03:17.157] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[16904:17532:0211/180317.159:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(239)] END: GetDefaultBrowser()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\!!!Angela\Paid screen scraper\data scraping\data scraping\my_ui_scrapy12.py", line 278, in show_page
    By.XPATH, "//*[@id='viewContainer']/app-listing-container/app-search-container/app-search-form-container/form/div[3]/button[2]").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
 c:\data scraping\data scraping> [22108:16084:0211/180503.560:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(454)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is
```

Answer (score 0):

### find_elements()

[find_elements()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements) find elements and returns a list, given a `By` strategy and locator.

So this line of code:

```
search_btn = self.driver.find_elements( By.XPATH, "//[@id='viewContainer']/app-listing-container/app-search-container/app-search-form-container/form/div[3]/button[2]")
```

would return a *list* and list has no method as [*click()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077251/7429447). Hence the next line:

```
search_btn.click()
```

raises the error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

---

### Solution

Replace [*find_elements()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71025446/7429447) with [*find_element()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136633/7429447) you would be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for that but I still get an error

Comment: @VirginiaWalters I'm certainly sure you don't see _AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'_ anymore. Can you please confirm?

Comment: raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='viewContainer']/app-listing-container/app-search-container/app-search-form-container/form/div[3]/button[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.82)

Comment: Still getting an error by click error is gone

Comment: @VirginiaWalters _`NoSuchElementException`_ is a different error all together and can be solved as well. Feel free to raise a new question with your new requirement.