# Selenium Exception NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When running this code after making changes form find_element_by_xpath to find_element(By.XPATH I am now encountering an error of not be able to locate the element.

```
        search_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='viewContainer']/app-listing-container/app-search-container/app-search-form-container/form/div[3]/button[2]")
        time.sleep(4)
        search_btn.click()
        time.sleep(5)
'''
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:63724/devtools/browser/c4f952a3-afd0-4074-8aaf-452394b3300d
[22840:23968:0212/182455.570:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(227)] START: ReportBluetoothAvailability(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[22840:23968:0212/182455.570:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] END: ReportBluetoothAvailability()
[22840:23968:0212/182455.571:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(235)] START: GetDefaultBrowser(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[22840:19460:0212/182455.579:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:24:55.579] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[22840:19460:0212/182455.587:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:24:55.587] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[22840:23968:0212/182455.590:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(239)] END: GetDefaultBrowser()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\!!!Angela\Paid screen scraper\data scraping\data scraping\my_ui_scrapy12.py", line 277, in show_page
    search_btn = self.driver.find_element(
  File "C:\Users\vwalt_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1244, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\vwalt_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 424, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\vwalt_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='viewContainer']/app-listing-container/app-search-container/app-search-form-container/form/div[3]/button[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=98.0.4758.82)
```

Comment: You are using my proposed [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71096077/7429447) to your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71087893/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-click-using-find-elementby-xpa) without providing a proper feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception message is quite clear:

> NoSuchElementException

Have you ***tried your XPATH*** - if it gives exactly the right element?

For now it looks like:

> //*[@id='viewContainer']/app-listing-container/app-search-container/app-search-form-container/form/div[3]/button[2]

Much better will be depicted for which exactly element has such `id`, like:

> //button[@id='id-name']

And try to omit

> div[3]/button[2]

if more elements (like more buttons) will be added your XPATH fails.

Also, it could be that this element hasn't been loaded yet. You could add [explicit wait](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/wait-commands-in-selenium-webdriver).

**UPDATE:**

For processing ***Xpath*** locators from page you able to use extension for Firefox browser:

- [FirePath](https://addons.mozilla.org/uk/firefox/addon/firepath/)
- [Xpath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/)

You could use the browser's console for it as well.

Comment: This is code I did not create and I am new to trying to understand it. I am not sure what the ID  for the button  is it button.btn.rt-btn-primary.searchBtn

Comment: The code was working till the change of find_element_by_xpath to find_element(By.XPATH) your closing this is not correct as your answer is refering to the old method and has not provided me an answer

Comment: @VirginiaWalters I am afraid it is the answer. You didn't share any details about page structure. If the XPath is correct everything should work fine

Comment: #viewContainer > app-listing-container > app-search-container > app-search-panel-container > div > div > app-search-panel > div.searchBtnContainer.open > button.btn.rt-btn-primary.searchBtn

Comment: sorry I am new to the tools and am using my hit or miss method. I believe that is wht I am trying to find then click

Comment: Thank you for the information  I finally figured out how to determine xpath in chrome browser.