# No such element error but the element can be located in the DOM through xpath expression

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have a python script logging into our company website to then get each row of data. It logs me in, locates the iframe where the table with row values is located, from there I try to locate a row in the iframe table and attached is a picture:

[image: xpathexpression]

Highlighting the correct xpath expression but I need all 31 values.

All my code works properly except this:

```
elem5 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//td/label[contains(@id, 'driver')][1]")
```

Answer (score 2):

[*`find_element_by_*`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136633/7429447) returns a single webelement, where as you are looking for all the ***31*** elements. So you need [*`find_elements*`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71025446/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td > label[id^='driver']")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td/label[starts-with(@id, 'driver')]")
  ```

---

To find all the desired elements ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49775808/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "td > label[id^='driver']")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//td/label[starts-with(@id, 'driver')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```