# Selenium 3.141.0 - send_keys() work fine on Windows but don't on Linux Debian 11

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, debian

I try to do some web automation with Selenium.

My program was working good until I upgrade my packages - Now the `send_keys()` don't work on linux but it do well on Windows with the same versions.

I tried to 1 `click()`, 2 `clear()`, 3 `send_keys()` - copy/pasting, etc...

But none of these make the javascript input saving my `send_keys(string)`. It do send the keys, but after he goes to next action, string has gone... And there's no error in console neither in logs.

I also tried with **selenium 4.1.3** but it don't change anything...

It work perfectly under windows with/out headless, but it has stop working on Debian 11 Rolling after an update...

Please give me hint it's very important !!

**Selenium version 3.141.0**

**Chrome version 100.0.4896.88-1**

**Python version 3.9.12**

**Kernel version 5.16.0**

Comment: same issue for me, did you find any solution or workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Don't just [find_element()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136633/7429447) to invoke `send_keys(string)`.

Ideally, you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following solution:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "element_css")))
element.click()
element.clear()
element.send_keys("HSMKU")
```

Comment: It's already what I did, as I explained. The script work perfectly under windows but don't under linux... I introduce a WebDriverWait, I even have a customDOMwaiter that wait for element event we want to do incase the DOM event load is delayed... I don't understand :( !!!