# text based HTML of the element selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I am actually trying to scrap a website. In fact I have a table like this below :

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yB5a.png)

I would like to navigate to the line that contains the word "Maître", but I am not able to find this line with selenium. Below the html code of the page :

[Html code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uan9K.png)
[Html code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0MEV.png)

And this is my code :

```
objets_de_risque = driver.find_element(By.ID,'sidebar-link-0-1')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", objets_de_risque)
code_h = driver.find_element(By.ID,'input-search-1')
code_h.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + "a")
code_h.send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
code_h.send_keys("H1404")
code_h.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
driver.switch_to_frame("main1")
line_maitre = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Maître')]")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", line_maitre)
```

The last 2 lines doesn't seem to work. Is there a way to go to this line with selenium ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[find_elements()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71025446/7429447) returns a *list*. Instead you need [find_element()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136633/7429447) to locate the element.

---

### Solution

To locate a ***visible*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  line_maitre = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[text()=''Maître'']")))
  ```

However to click on it as per your code in a single line:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//td[text()=''Maître'']"))))
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Actually, I would like to double click on it not just a single click. I read about ActionChains. I wrote this line `actionChains = ActionChains(line_maitre)` but I get an error message telling me `'WebElement' object has no attribute 'w3c'`

Comment: Sounds to be a different question all together. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirements.