# How to check that user input correct email for recovery account by selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I tried:

```py
search_recover_login_button.click()
try:
    myElem3 = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*locator').text
    return "You've got your password reset!" in myElem3
except TimeoutException:
    print ('No users found with this email')
 message = driver.find_element('xpath', '//*"]/h1').text
 assert message == "You've got your password reset!"
```

but it doesn't work, even when an incorrect email is used, it always looks OK.

I need to get results:
1 - when user input incorrect email, he will not see the massage "You've got your password reset!" and test will be failed, but when input correct, he go next page and see the message "You've got your password reset!" and test is pass

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element _"You've got your password reset!"_ and the actual locators.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider a couple of things:

- [*`find_element()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136633/7429447) on failure will return [*NoSuchElementException*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447). So if you use [`find_element()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66136633/7429447) you have to catch and handle [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447) in the except block.
- While extracting text ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447).
- So your effective code block can be:

  ```
  search_recover_login_button.click()
  try:
      myElem3 = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*locator"))).text
  except TimeoutException:
      print ('No users found with this email')
  message = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*"]/h1"))).text
  assert message == "You've got your password reset!"
  ```

Comment: and one more thing: when i input icorrect email, it answer me that "reset password" != "You've got ..." looks like no wait for timeout, just make assert every time

Comment: its because every time locator is same, just only phrase changes

Comment: i've use this one

        try:
            myElem3 = WebDriverWait(driver, delay3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[text()="You' 've got your password reset!"]'))).text
        except TimeoutException:
            print('No users found with this email')
        message = WebDriverWait(driver, delay3).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[text()="You' 've got your password reset!"]'))).text
        assert message == "You' 've got your password reset!"

but now it's every time show me timeout message, but next page with this phrase appear..