# Selenium Python | Type in input

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, nosuchelementexception

[image]

I am trying to type into the input category using selenium on Python google chrome. I would like to send the keys 1234 to test the configuration, however, I am receiving errors. I believe I am missing something from the code... Sorry if this is super basic, I am still learning selenium... I tried using the @class already and received an error.

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[='']/parent::div").send_keys('1234')`

I am getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[9]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/input"}   
(Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)
```

I have concluded the html should represent value=1234, however, I still am struggling with the code.

Comment: Firstly, what errors, second try right clicking in inspector then Copy>Copy full xpath.

Comment: I'm need to type where the value is; I am struggling with this... Here's the xpath: `/html/body/div[9]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/input`

Comment: I think the problem is your xpath is incorrect. Correct your xpath will solve the problem.

Comment: paste that xpath instead of the old one

Comment: Can you post html in text format instead of image and part of your code as well ? It easier for us to give you correct answer. Link to the website you are working with even better.

Comment: I am getting this error `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[9]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.150)`

Comment: Check if it's in a iframe or shadow root.

Comment: Why to use full xpath?...You can use relative xpath. For start use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chropath/ljngjbnaijcbncmcnjfhigebomdlkcjo . And try some tutorial with selectors like: https://www.guru99.com/locators-in-selenium-ide.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.[aria-label='Amount'][placeholder='0']").send_keys("1234")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Amount' and @placeholder='0']").send_keys("1234")
  ```

---

The desired element is a dynamic element, so ideally to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.[aria-label='Amount'][placeholder='0']"))).send_keys("1234")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Amount' and @placeholder='0']"))).send_keys("1234")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)