# Why am I unable to click submit button of "Accept Cookies" popup?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to scrape some data from a genealogy website, I need to log in but I can't click with Selenium the Submit button, it may be because I need to accept the cookies but I can't click it as well.

Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

PATH = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get("https://en.geneanet.org/connexion/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tarteaucitronPersonalize2"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_id("_username").send_keys('user')
driver.find_element_by_id ("_password").send_keys("pwd")
driver.find_element_by_id("_submit").click()
```

The button looks like this:

[image]

This is the HTML corresponding to the button "Submit":
Submit

The cookies popup and HTML looks like this:

[image]

I get the following error messages:

```
(vscrap) admin@Admins-MacBook-Pro V2 % /Users/admin/Documents/Coding/Python/Scrapping/vscrap/bin/python /Users/admin/Documents/Coding/Python/Scrapping/UpWork/V2/Selenium_login-immo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Coding/Python/Scrapping/UpWork/V2/Selenium_login-immo.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id("_submit").click()
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Coding/Python/Scrapping/vscrap/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Coding/Python/Scrapping/vscrap/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Coding/Python/Scrapping/vscrap/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Coding/Python/Scrapping/vscrap/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" class="button-register no-margin-bottom large">...</button> is not clickable at point (429, 324). Other element would receive the click: <div id="tarteaucitronRoot" class="tarteaucitronBeforeVisible">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.69)

(vscrap) admin@Admins-MacBook-Pro V2 % /Users/admin/Documents/Coding/Python/Scrapping/vscrap/bin/python /Users/admin/Documents/Coding/Python/Scrapping/UpWork/V2/Selenium_login-immo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Coding/Python/Scrapping/UpWork/V2/Selenium_login-immo.py", line 15, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id("_submit").click()
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Coding/Python/Scrapping/vscrap/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Coding/Python/Scrapping/vscrap/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Coding/Python/Scrapping/vscrap/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/admin/Documents/Coding/Python/Scrapping/vscrap/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <button type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" class="button-register no-margin-bottom large">...</button> is not clickable at point (429, 324). Other element would receive the click: <div id="tarteaucitronRoot" class="tarteaucitronBeforeVisible">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=95.0.4638.69)
```

Why can't I click this Submit button?

Answer (score 1):

The <kbd>OK, accept all</kbd> button is a dynamic element, so ideally to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.tarteaucitronCTAButton.tarteaucitronAllow#tarteaucitronPersonalize2"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='tarteaucitronCTAButton tarteaucitronAllow' and @id='tarteaucitronPersonalize2']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: thanks, i have added the missing import and the webDriverWait but still the same the cookies popup remains and the submit has not been clicked.

Comment: I added a short delay to it and then it worked. 

    `w_item =      WebDriverWait(driver,50).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.tarteaucitronCTAButton.tarteaucitronAllow#tarteaucitronPersonalize2")))

    time.sleep(1)

    w_item.click()`