# Unable to send text to Leaving from field within expedia.com using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

On website https://www.expedia.com/ i need to type on the Leaving from colum,but it only gives me an error:AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'. How can i write on Leaving from?

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver


driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\ChromeDriverExtracted\chromedriver")

driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("https://www.expedia.com/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Flights']").click()

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=wizard-flight-tab-roundtrip]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/button").send_keys("SFO")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using CSS_SELECTOR:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.expedia.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[aria-controls='wizard-flight-pwa']>span"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='Leaving from']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#location-field-leg1-origin"))).send_keys("SFO")
  ```
- Using XPATH:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.expedia.com/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-controls='wizard-flight-pwa']//span"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Leaving from']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='location-field-leg1-origin']"))).send_keys("SFO")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: expedia_from_SFO]

- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: It opens the drop menu but It isn't sending the keys ("SFO"). Suggestions?

Comment: See the snapshot, sends _SFO_ clearly at my end

Comment: It worked. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your last "find_element_by_xpath" does not correctly locate the element you are looking for.  An xpath that does locate your element is

```
"//input[@id='location-field-leg1-origin-input']"
```

I don't think this will completely solve your problem though.  One thing is that you need to click on this element rather than simply send keys to it.  You need to open the modal where you actually enter and select the airport you are leaving from.

Comment: Tried it. Error: ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned you cannot type on that element.  The website wants you to interact with it to open the modal where you do type and select an airport.

Comment: Ok i tried just with click() but the error message is: Message: element not interactable. 
   river.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='location-field-leg1-origin-input']").click()