# Selenium: Why inputs values don't preserve the given values?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autocomplete, webdriverwait

I'm facing the following issue with Selenium:

[image: Quotation Web Page]

I've successfully completed the fields "Origen" and "Destino", however, the values ​​after the script occurs, disappear.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


#Opciones navegacion
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

driver_path = "C:/Users/Diego/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options = options)
 

#Iniciar en la pantalla 2
#driver.set_window_position(2000,0)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)

#Inicializamos el navegador
driver.get('https://www.starken.cl/cotizador')

WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#rc_select_6"))).send_keys('SANTIAGO')
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#rc_select_7"))).send_keys('VINA DEL MAR')
```

I'll be thankful for any suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: looks like it's requiring you to select one of the auto-suggest values... a sort of combobox there?

Comment: Exactly! It's a combobox.

Answer (score 1):

These `<input>`s are ant based input boxes with a role of *combobox* which generates [autocomplete](/questions/tagged/autocomplete) from which you have to select one.

To send the *character sequence* ***SANTIAGO*** to the element and select it from the *auto-suggestions* you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[text()='Origen:']//following::div[1]//span[@class='ant-select-selection-search']/input[@class='ant-select-selection-search-input']"))).send_keys('SANTIAGO')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@title='SANTIAGO']/div[@class='ant-select-item-option-content' and text()='SANTIAGO']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: www_starken_cl_cotizador]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes with dropdowns, a user input is required to confirm the selection can be mouse click or the enter button. I went for the latter. I also added some time to your wait function as it took longer for the page to load where I am, and the wait expired. This is only a "wait for up to" not a "wait for."

It's also worth mentioning if your input results in multiple items, you may need to make a further selection; i.e. which item from those results?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time


#Opciones navegacion
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

#driver_path = "C:/Users/Diego/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
 

#Iniciar en la pantalla 2
#driver.set_window_position(2000,0)
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(1)

#Inicializamos el navegador
driver.get('https://www.starken.cl/cotizador')
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#rc_select_6"))).send_keys('SANTIAGO' + u'\ue007' )
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#rc_select_7"))).send_keys('VINA DEL MAR' + u'\ue007')
```