# How to interact with Login pop-up using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, popup, webdriverwait

```
import openpyxl
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
chrome_options = Options()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

sheet = wb.active
sheet.append(["1lable", "2lable"])
wb.save("save.xlsx")
path = "/Users/erer/Desktop/도구/파이썬 작업공간./chromedriver 2"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path , chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://otr.co.kr/#!')

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#site-header > div > a").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#login-panel-1767 > form > div > div > div.form-group.label-floating.is-empty.is-focused").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#login-panel-1767 > form > div > div > div.form-group.label-floating.is-empty.is-focused").send_keys(" (개인정보라 비워둡니다.) ")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#login-panel-1205 > form > div > div > div.form-group.label-floating.password-eye-wrap.is-empty > input").send_keys("비밀번호라 비워둡니다.")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#login-panel-1205 > form > div > div > button").click()
```

https://otr.co.kr/#!

If you go into this link and press login popup on the top right, a popup that allows you to log in will be executed.
Even if you apply css selectors, and other things in Selenium, you can't enter your ID password.
I need the help of experts.

Comment: What error you get? the number after login-panel-X is always same or it changes?

Answer (score 1):

To send a *character sequence* to *ID* field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [`element_to_be_clickable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://otr.co.kr/?ckattempt=1")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.side-menu-open>i.olympus-icon-Active-Members-Icon"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div#registration-login-form-popup input.form-control.simple-input[name='log']"))).send_keys("김진우")
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: otr_ko_kr]

- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong locators and missing waits / delays.
Try this, it should work

```py
import openpyxl
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
chrome_options = Options()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
options.add_argument("disable-gpu")

sheet = wb.active
sheet.append(["1lable", "2lable"])
wb.save("save.xlsx")
path = "/Users/erer/Desktop/도구/파이썬 작업공간./chromedriver 2"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path , chrome_options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('https://otr.co.kr/#!')

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#site-header > div > a"))).click()
username = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='modal-content']//input[@name='log' and(@class='form-control simple-input')]")))
username.click()
username.send_keys(" (개인정보라 비워둡니다.) ")
pwd_input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='modal-content']//input[@name='pwd' and(@class='form-control simple-input')]")))
pwd_input.send_keys("비밀번호라 비워둡니다.")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='modal-content']//button[@type='submit']").click()
```

Comment: webdriverwait is not defined

Comment: I added the required imports

Comment: wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
NameError: name 'driver' is not defined

Comment: But in your code there is `driver.get('https://otr.co.kr/#!')` and `driver.find_element_by_css_selector` several times. How it worked before?

Comment: I changed the cord
And since, ID, password and login window is down to the behavior of the last click and be input by I don't.

Comment: i don't understand you