# How to select the right size of a product? Selenium - ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriverwait

My Code:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/rober/OneDrive/Skrivebord/bot/chromedriver')

# Graffik kort
browser.get("https://www.zalando.dk/jordan-air-jordan-1-mid-sneakers-high-joc12n001-a18.html")

buyButton = False

while buyButton is False:

    try:
        
        addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/x-wrapper-re-1-6/div/div[4]/button')

        print("Varen er udsolgt")

        time.sleep(1)
        browser.refresh()

    except:
        addToCartBtn = addButton = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="picker-trigger"]')

        print("Varen er på Lager")
        buyButton = True

while buyButton is True:
    time.sleep(3)
    accept = browser.find_element_by_id('uc-btn-accept-banner')
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", accept) 
    element = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="picker-trigger"]')))
    element.click();
```

My Error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="uc-btn-accept-banner"]"}
```

[The link to the Website](https://www.zalando.dk/jordan-air-jordan-1-mid-sneakers-high-joc12n001-a18.html)

My problem is that i want to get the size 51.5 in eu sizes but i don't know the code to select that size with the CLASS of the size.

If some one know a solution, just make a comment because i really need some help to find the right solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select the size as ***51.5*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Code Block:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.zalando.dk/jordan-air-jordan-1-mid-sneakers-high-joc12n001-a18.html")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.uc-btn#uc-btn-accept-banner"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Vælg størrelse']"))).click()
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[starts-with(@for, 'size-picker')]//span[text()='51.5']"))))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[starts-with(@for, 'size-picker')]//span[text()='51.5']"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: 51.5]

- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: And why are you adding button.uc-btn in front of the css_selector "button.uc-btn#uc-btn-accept-banner"

Comment: _button_ is the tag_name, which have one of it's classnames as _uc-btn_ with id as _uc-btn-accept-banner_