# How to find_element(By.XPATH) and sending keys in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, xpath, webdriver

Trying to update my code to use `"driver.find_element(By.XPATH..."` instead of `"driver.find_elements_by_xpath(..."`, but I keep getting the following the error when I send keys:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Here is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
link_login = "https://www.wyzant.com/tutor/jobs"

driver.get(link_login)

username_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Username']")[1]
username_input.send_keys("Test")
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `find_elements` instead of `find_element` to select the element like you do in your example:

```
driver.get('https://www.wyzant.com/tutor/jobs')
username_input = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='Username']")[1]
username_input.send_keys("Test")
```

or change your xpath to select more specific `'//form[@class="sso-login-form"]//*[@id="Username"]'`:

```
driver.get('https://www.wyzant.com/tutor/jobs')
username_input = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//form[@class="sso-login-form"]//*[@id="Username"]')
username_input.send_keys("Test")
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Try using more precise XPath locator.
2. The entire XPath expression should be inside the `(By.XPATH, "your_xpath_expression")`
3. You should also use expected conditions explicit waits

This should work:

```py
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@action='/sso/login']//input[@id='Username']"))).send_keys(your_user_name)
```

You will need to import these imports:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* within the ***Username*** field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.wyzant.com/tutor/jobs")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "form.sso-login-form input#Username"))).send_keys("rushi")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.wyzant.com/tutor/jobs")   
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//form[@class='sso-login-form']//input[@id='Username']"))).send_keys("rushi")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```