# Find and click an element using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to have my program click on an element on a site.  Below are the HTML, XPath, & Full XPATH that I copied from the site:

HTML

```
<a role="button" class="list_filter_toggle icon-filter btn btn-icon" tabindex="0" title="Show / hide filter" id="incident_filter_toggle_image" aria-controls="incidentfilterdiv" aria-expanded="true" data-original-title="Show / hide filter"><span class="sr-only">Show / hide filter</span></a>
```

XPATH

```
//*[@id="incident_filter_toggle_image"]
```

Full XPATH

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/span/div/div[4]/div[1]/a
```

Below is the code that I'm running and feel that is the closest to success because 1, did not return a bunch of errors back and 2, it at least printed an empty list:

## my code:

```
go = browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id=incident_filter_toggle_image]")
print(go)
go.click()
```

## From the Console:

```
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxxxx\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\service.py", line 24, in <module>
    go.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

## Below are some other variation that I attempted but had no luck:

```
go = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'incident_filter_toggle_image')

go = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@title id="incident_filter_toggle_image"]')
go = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[id=incident_filter_toggle_image])
go = browser.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@title="Show / hide filter"]')

go = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "list_filter_toggle icon-filter btn btn-icon")
go = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, ".//breadcrumb_container[@id="incident_filter_toggle_image"]")

go = browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id=incident_filter_toggle_image]" )
go = browser.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[id=incident_filter_toggle_image]")
```

Comment: My HTML code did not save correctly on my post. Here's the element HTML Script:
=========================================================
<a role="button" class="list_filter_toggle icon-filter btn btn-icon" tabindex="0" title="Show / hide filter" id="incident_filter_toggle_image" aria-controls="incidentfilterdiv" aria-expanded="true" data-original-title="Show / hide filter"><span class="sr-only">Show / hide filter</span></a>

Comment: If you're looking for one element you should use `find_element` instead of `find_elements`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70571647/2681662

Comment: If `browser.find_element(By.ID, 'incident_filter_toggle_image')` did not work, then I can only assume that there is in fact no such element.  Are you sure it isn't inside a `<frame>`?

Comment: @JohnGordon - thank you for your quick response!  From what I can tell, the element is in an iframe but its the frame of the site's main pane:           
        <iframe id="gsft_main" allowfullscreen="true" main-pane="true" name="gsft_main" title=".......           Further down in the html code, the element is within this div class:     
<div class="breadcrumb_container" colspan="99">    I'm not sure if that helps...

Comment: Frames are essentially their own separate self-contained web pages.  If an element is in a frame, you have to tell selenium to switch to the frame.  https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/frames/#using-a-webelement

Comment: I got it!!  Thank you so much!  that doc was extremely helpful!   I do have one last question..    The next element that Im attempting to get next is a text field and the ID ends with alphanumberic characters that changes everytime the page refreshes.   Is it possible to locate an id with something in the nature of: id name contains [sys_display.incident.cmdb.] or ID = sys_display.incident.cmdb.[anything]?

Comment: @JohnGordon - I got it!  I figure out my latest problem!  I was able to locate the element via XPATH.  thank you again!