# ElementNotInteractableException sending text tn a Search box using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Im new on this coding stuff and im trying to access this search box from this website but i keep getting errors.
When i try the same stuff on other websites it work but for some reason i cant do it here.
https://shop.cummins.com/

This is the website:

[image: This is the website]

This is my code:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Browserpath)
website = "https://shop.cummins.com/"
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(website)

CumminsSearch =driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/c-dbu_home-page-header/div/header/div/div/div[4]/c-dbu_custom-search/div/form/lightning-input[2]/div/input")

time.sleep(10)

CumminsSearch.send_keys("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(//input[@placeholder='Search'])[1]
```

Use this xpath to get a unique identifier. Also use webdriver waits to allow the element to interactable.

```
CumminsSearch = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//input[@placeholder='Search'])[1]")))
CumminsSearch.send_keys("test")
```

Imports:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the *Search* field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "lightning-input[class*='dWindow'] input.slds-input[placeholder='Search']"))).send_keys("Wilbert Balbuena")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//lightning-input[contains(@class, 'dWindow')]//input[@class='slds-input' and @placeholder='Search']"))).send_keys("Wilbert Balbuena")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: shop_cummins]