# How to write a value for input tag created by ion-input using selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, ionic-framework, xpath, css-selectors

I have ion-input tags in my app and that creates another input tag as a sibling. The sibling input is responsible for any input value.

I want to access that sibling to enter a value using selenium Python (can be using `send_keys` or using `javascript_executor`

```
<ion-input data-cy="email" type="email" debounce="50" value="" class="sc-ion-input-md-h sc-ion-input-md-s md">
  <input class="native-input sc-ion-input-md" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off" 
  autocorrect="off" name="ion-input-0" placeholder="" spellcheck="false" type="email"></ion-input>
```

Everytime I use that `data-cy="email"` I am getting elementNotFound exception only.

I am using Selenium python.

Comment: Please share a link to the page you are working on and your code attempts

Answer (score 0):

The element should be unique in nature, based on the HTML that you've shared, can you check this CSS or XPATH

**XPATH:**

```
//input[@class='native-input sc-ion-input-md' and @type='email' and@name='ion-input-0']
```

**CSS_SELECTOR:**

```
input[class='native-input sc-ion-input-md'][type='email'][name='ion-input-0']
```

Please check in the `dev tools` (Google chrome) if we have **unique** entry in `HTML DOM` or not.

**Steps to check:**

`Press F12 in Chrome` -> go to `element` section -> do a `CTRL  + F` -> then paste the `xpath/css` and see, if your desired `element` is getting **highlighted** with `1/1` matching node.

If they happen to be unique in nature you can try with the below code:

**Code1:**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='native-input sc-ion-input-md' and @type='email' and@name='ion-input-0']")))
input.send_keys('the string that you want to send')
```

**Code2:**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
input = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='native-input sc-ion-input-md' and @type='email' and@name='ion-input-0']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'the string that you want to send')", input)
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I was able to access the element using ```@type='email'``` or ```@name='ion-input-0']``` however, on the other screens i have got multiple input elements where the names are dynamic. hence have asked the developer to add a custom attribute ```data-cy="<<field_name>>"``` so that it will be always unique.
Hence my question is... How can i access the inner ```<input ``` tag within ```ion-input``` using the custom attribute ```data-cy``` inorder maintain the uniqueness across the app

Comment: I am using something like this as i am obligated to use the custom-attribute 
```email = [(By.XPATH, "ion-input[data-cy='email'] input")]```

Answer (score 0):

I don't any such major issues in your code attempts. However the the desired element is a dynamic element, so ideally to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ion-input[data-cy='email'] > input[type='email'][name^='ion-input']"))).send_keys("Sarath@N.com")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ion-input[@data-cy='email']/input[@type='email' and starts-with(@name, 'ion-input')]"))).send_keys("Sarath@N.com")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

It was so easy. I have been using either XPATH or CSS_SELECTOR hence always it does not penetrate to the input tag that was created by ion. Instead of the bespoke one, i have used TAGNAME and that did the magic

```
email = [(By.XPATH, "ion-input[data-cy='email'] input")]
```

Instead use like this

```
email = [(By.TAGNAME, "ion-input[data-cy='email']")]
```