# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException error sending text to input fields using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to write a simple program to fill out a form (including order ID and zip code) to be submitted but I keep getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: "  (without any text following "Message
```

Code trials:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Safari()
browser.get('https://knowledge.tonal.com/s/order-status')

orderElm = browser.find_element_by_id('input-3')
orderElm.send_keys('1000XXX')

zipcodeElm = browser.find_element_by_id('input-4')
zipcodeElm.send_keys('90210')
zipcodeElm.submit()
```

I've double-checked my element ID several times and though I'm very new to this, I'm fairly confident I have the correct element IDs.  What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65140218/selenium-not-able-to-click-on-get-data-button-on-using-python/65141861#65141861) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://knowledge.tonal.com/s/order-status")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@data-aura-class='cOrderSearch']//following::input[1]"))).send_keys('1000XXX')
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@data-aura-class='cOrderSearch']//following::input[2]").send_keys("90210")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: tonal_com]

Comment: Outstanding!  Thanks for the added context.  This worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

There are mutliple issues here:
A. After getting the url, you are not waiting for the elements in the page to load completely and hence the elements are not found
B. The locators you have seem dynamic to me, for eg: `input-3`, I see it as `input-5` (although I am on Chrome browser, but that may not rule out that the locators are dynamic). So, I refactored and hunted for some static locator strategies which I pasted below.
C. `zipcodeElm.submit()` would not work, as it is not the button element. I have refactored this too.
So, here is the code.

```
driver.get('https://knowledge.tonal.com/s/order-status')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@data-aura-class='cOrderSearch']//input)[1]")))
orderElm = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@data-aura-class='cOrderSearch']//input)[1]")
orderElm.send_keys('1000XXX')
zipcodeElm = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//div[@data-aura-class='cOrderSearch']//input)[2]")
zipcodeElm.send_keys('90210')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@data-aura-class='cOrderSearch']//parent::div//button").click()
```

Output: (exit code 0 implies that the code passed without errors)

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Hmmm...No.  That prints the same error.

Comment: @Mfrazz, that was my prima-facie. But now I have given a detailed answer. Please check. It should work now.