# How to click on the Sign up button on Spotify sign up page using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, spotify

I can't click "sign up" button on Spotify sign up page . I found button xpath or css but I can't click. I tried "click text" but same result.

```py
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div/form/div[9]/div'))).click()
```

Comment: Update the question with the error stacktrace.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium - wait until element is present, visible and interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable)

Answer (score 0):

To click on the <kbd>Sign up</kbd> element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.spotify.com/in-en/signup')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#onetrust-close-btn-container>button[aria-label='Close']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#email"))).send_keys("ggforces@stackoverflow.com")
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']>div").click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.spotify.com/in-en/signup')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='onetrust-close-btn-container']/button[@aria-label='Close']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='email']"))).send_keys("ggforces@stackoverflow.com")
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@type='submit']/div").click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: spotify_signup]