# How to find element for login details for Selenium using Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am just learning Selenium using Python. I used BBC web page, however I am not sure how I can add the code for the following screen. All I need is the code to identify the field "Email or username" and "Password". Please see the screenshot. My code looks like this at the moment.

```
driver.get("https://www.bbc.co.uk/")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='header-content']/div[2]/nav/div[1]/div/div[1]/ul[2]/li[1]/a/span[2]").click()
ele = driver.find_element(By.NAME("Email or username"))
```

Snapshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the *Email or username* field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.bbc.co.uk/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span#idcta-username"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']"))).send_keys("Denny_Thampi")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www.bbc.co.uk/')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='idcta-username']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']"))).send_keys("Denny_Thampi")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: bbc_sign_in]

Comment: amazing. Thank you very much :-)