# Unable to click on suggestion provided by textbox (Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

When I send text manually, suggestion area provided by first textbox , it works fine. But when I send the text using selenium library it cannot able to select the option from suggestion area, although that option is present inside the textbox. Is there any one who can help me out of that.

[image]

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
path=r"C:\Users\AbdulRehman\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
# driver =  webdriver.Chrome(path)
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())

driver.get("https://www4.sii.cl/mapasui/internet/#/contenido/index.html")


try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ng-app"]/body/div[5]/div/div/div[3]/div/button'))
         )
    element.click()
    print("prints its working fine now ..")
    
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="titulo"]/div[8]/i'))
         )
    element.click()
    
#     element = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(
#         EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="rolsearch"]/div[2]/div[1]/input'))
#          )

#     element.send_keys("PEDRO AGUIRRE CERD"+Keys.ENTER)

#     search = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
#         EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rolsearch"]/div[2]/div[1]/input'))
#     )
#     search.send_keys("EL MONTE" + Keys.ENTER)
#     time.sleep(3)
    search = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="rolsearch"]/div[2]/div[1]/input'))
    )
    ActionChains(driver).click(on_element=search).send_keys("EL MONTE").send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()

    suggestion = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//strong[text()="EL MONTE"]'))
    )
    suggestion.click()
#     auto_complete = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="rolsearch"]/div[2]/div[1]/input')
#     auto_complete[0].click()
#     auto_complete.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
#     element.send_keys("somehting in text")
#     search =  driver.find_element_by_xpath().click()
    
#     search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    search_1 =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rolsearch"]/div[2]/div[2]/input')
    search_1.send_keys("PEDRO AGUIRRE CERDA")
    search_1.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

    search_2 =  driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rolsearch"]/div[2]/div[3]/input')
    search_2.send_keys("somehting in text")
    search_2.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
    
    print("Its also working now ......")
    
    time.sleep(3)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, so to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [element_to_be_clickable()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use the following [Locator Strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://www4.sii.cl/mapasui/internet/#/contenido/index.html')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Aceptar']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//i[@data-ng-click='mostrarBusquedaRol()']"))).click()
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@data-ng-include, '/mapasui/common/_content/busqueda-rol.html')]//div[@id='rolsearch']//label[contains(., 'Comuna')]//following::input[1]"))).send_keys("PEDRO AGUIRRE CERD" + Keys.ENTER)
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: mapasui]

Comment: in your screenshot its also showing the same error. Isn't it ?

Comment: @AbdulRehman Where do you see the error? You mean the line below the input box? Is that an error message?

Comment: yes sir That what I am facing to