# How to insert some text within the input using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

In a webpage I have the following element:

```
<div id="learning_form" class="learning_form">
                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                    <tbody><tr><td><input type="text" id="answer" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Odpowiedź" style="width: 360px;"></td></tr>
                </tbody></table>
                <div id="check"><h4 style="text-align: center;">Sprawdź</h4></div>
                <div id="special_characters"><div>&nbsp;</div><div>&nbsp;</div></div>
            </div>
```

How I can insert text here using selenium in python?
I tried using:

```
driver.find_element(By.ID,"learning_form").send_keys("some text")
```

but it doesn't work.

Snapshot of the element:

[image]

Comment: What is "Sprawdz"?  Are you sure the element's ID is exactly "learning_form"?

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.learning_form#learning_form input#answer[placeholder='Odpowiedź']"))).send_keys("OłJeż")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='learning_form' and @id='learning_form']//input[@id='answer' and @placeholder='Odpowiedź']"))).send_keys("OłJeż")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#answer"))).send_keys("value")
```

It seems you need to send values to the input with an id answer.

```
<input type="text" id="answer" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Odpowiedź" style="width: 360px;">
```

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```