# Enter text within text box using xpath in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to locate a text box to enter a text in it but couldn't because of the error 'no such element: Unable to locate element'

Here is the HTML of the page:

```html
<form id="aaaSub" name="aaaSub" method="post" action="/ProvGwAaaGui/faces/jsp/dspAAABySearch.jsp" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="aaaSub" value="aaaSub" />
<table id="aaaSub:msg1" style="height:30px; margin-left:20px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="aaaSub:heading" style="height:60px; margin-left:20px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><table class="ad_wa_title_bold">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Display Single Umc AAA Subscriber</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table class="ad_wa_table" border="1" style="margin-left:20px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><table class="ad_wa_body" style="margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><table style="width:300px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><span id="aaaSub:j_id_jsp_2095096634_11" class="ad_wa_body">Identifier</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td><input id="aaaSub:identifier" name="aaaSub:identifier" type="text" value="" maxlength="32" size="30" onkeyup="disableOtherLink('aaaSub:identifier')" onchange="disableOtherLink('aaaSub:identifier')" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><table style="width:300px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><span id="aaaSub:j_id_jsp_2095096634_15" class="ad_wa_body">cn alias</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td><input id="aaaSub:cn" name="aaaSub:cn" type="text" value="" maxlength="32" size="30" onkeyup="disableOtherLink('aaaSub:cn')" onchange="disableOtherLink('aaaSub:cn')" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="aaaSub:empty" style="height:130px; margin-left:20px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><span id="aaaSub:j_id_jsp_2095096634_18"> </span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table id="aaaSub:buttons" class="ad_wa_body" style="width:200px;margin-left:20px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="aaaSub:j_id_jsp_2095096634_20" value="Display" style="height:25px;margin-left:5px;width:100px" onclick="return(mandatoryGeneralCheck())" /></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="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" autocomplete="off" />
</form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The requested box is here:

```
<td><input id="aaaSub:identifier" name="aaaSub:identifier" type="text" value="" maxlength="32" size="30" onkeyup="disableOtherLink('aaaSub:identifier')" onchange="disableOtherLink('aaaSub:identifier')" /></td>
```

I tried the following code

```python
web.implicitly_wait(30)
web.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="aaaSub:identifier"]').send_keys('text')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so ideally to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id='aaaSub:identifier'][name='aaaSub:identifier'][onchange*='aaaSub:identifier']"))).send_keys("text")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='aaaSub:identifier' and @name='aaaSub:identifier'][contains(@onchange, 'aaaSub:identifier')]"))).send_keys("text")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [***NoSuchElementException***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442511/7429447)

Comment: The xpath had worked well with me and give me the text in the text box but then it returned error "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException" even after changing wait time from 20 to 30 or decrease it to 10. The code stops at that point and dont continue "Process finished with exit code 1"

Answer (score 0):

You were using invalid xpath locator.
Please use `//input[@id="aaaSub:identifier"]`