# How to fix element not interactable using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

How to fix element not interactable selenium py

I want to input in address but its showing response like that

Element image:

[image]

My code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-group').click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('input- 
group').send_keys('sometext')
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
```

Answer (score 0):

I can’t test this but I think you cannot enter something in the div. You have to do get the input element by id. As the Id you enter: input-6199bf2c

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[contains(., 'Address')]//following::div[1]/input[starts-with(@id, 'input') and contains(@class, 'form-control-alternative')]"))).send_keys("PermataIndah")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```