# How to send text within username input field on a https://discord.com/register webpage with Selenium and Python3

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, discord.py

I'm trying to select the username text box in the https://discord.com/register website I tried:

```
driver.find_element ( by=By.CSS_SELECTOR ...)
driver.find_element ( by=By.CLASS_NAME ...)
driver.find_element ( by=By.CSS_XPATH ...)
```

They all didn't work . Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce WebDriverWait for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following *locator strategies*:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://discord.com/register')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='username']"))).send_keys("text")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://discord.com/register')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']"))).send_keys("tamer_mz")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: discord_username]

Comment: this code works thank you . but can you tell me how did you found out that the CSS_SELECTOR is a.btn and can you show me how to select the date of birth inputs they only have class names and i didn't know how to use them . thanks again

Comment: _CSS_SELECTOR as `a.btn`_ was a typo, corrected it.