# How to auto click on <a> tag using selenium (python) which calls a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

How do I access and click on a button which hyperlinks to a javascript function?

html element:

```
<a href="javascript:Nav('-index=')" id="ctl04_ctl25_ctl00_lnk2NextPg" class="twPagerBtn right" role="button" onclick="mySpud.container.scrollIntoView();" title="Next Page" aria-label="Next Page">►</a>
```

My current code:

```
next_button='//*[@id="ctl04_ctl06_ctl00_lnk2NextPg"]'
try:
    element=WebDriverWait(driver,15).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,next_button))
        
    )

    element.click()
except:
    driver.quit()
```

Selenium is unable to find the element and I've also tried using the find_element() function using various methods (by id etc) to no avail.

Comment: Did you try `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`

Answer (score 0):

The locator `//*[@id="ctl04_ctl06_ctl00_lnk2NextPg"]` doesn't seem to be static.

Try this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@aria-label='Next Page']"))).click()
```

If this doesn't work, then you can try this:

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@aria-label='Next Page']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Alternate locator:

You can use `//*[@title= 'Next Page']` instead of `@aria-label` locator
Alternate locator:

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care of a couple of things here:

- The initial part of the value of the `id` attribute is dynamic as in *`ctl04_ctl25_ctl00_lnk2NextPg`* and it would change everytime you access the page afresh. So you have to construct a ***dynamic*** [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver)
- Moving ahead as you are invoking `click()`, instead of *`presence_of_element_located()`* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following *locator strategies*:
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[id$='NextPg'][title='Next Page'][aria-label='Next Page']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@id, 'NextPg')][@title='Next Page' and @aria-label='Next Page']"))).click()
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function directly:

```
driver.execute_script("Nav('-index=')")
```