# How to send text within the Username field using Python Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I've been watching youtube videos, but cant seem to get the following to work using the "class method".

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options() options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get("https://sharemydata.pge.com/#login")
driver.find_element_by_class_name('input-username').send_keys('david@gmail.com')
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rj5zfP3ktgE
I watched this guys yt page, but his method byclass name does not seem to work for me. I can only seem to get as far as opening the page.

I also tried this,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']").send_keys("david@gmail.com")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* to the ***User Name*** field within the [website](https://sharemydata.pge.com/#login) you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='email']"))).send_keys("david@gmail.com")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='email']"))).send_keys("david@gmail.com")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: thanks!! how do i use the submit botton?

Comment: @gbdavidx Sounds to be a different question all together. Can you raise a new question with your new requirement please?