# How to delete the cookie consent popup element from the webpage using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

So, I'm trying to create a Script that opens a Google Chrome page and search "LMFAO", for example.
Only a problem: Cookies.
I want to learn how to delete a specific element from a webpage, in this case the Cookies Pop-up of youtube.

Here's the actual script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://youtube.com')

time.sleep(8)

driver.execute_script("""
   const ll = document.getElementById("dialog")[0];
   ll.remove();
""")

searchbox = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]')
searchbox.send_keys('LMFAO')
```

Cookie Popup snapshot:

[image: Here]

For the undetected Selenium Comment, here's the button html:

```
<tp-yt-paper-button id="button" class="style-scope ytd-button-renderer style-primary size-default" role="button" tabindex="0" animated="" elevation="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-label="Agree to the use of cookies and other data for the purposes described"><!--css-build:shady--><yt-formatted-string id="text" class="style-scope ytd-button-renderer style-primary size-default">I Agree</yt-formatted-string><paper-ripple class="style-scope tp-yt-paper-button"><!--css-build:shady-->
    

    <div id="background" class="style-scope paper-ripple"></div>
    <div id="waves" class="style-scope paper-ripple"></div>
</paper-ripple></tp-yt-paper-button>
```

Comment: _how to delete a specific element_: Which element are you trying to delete?

Comment: The dialog box of youtube cookies, when you open it in a new chrome non-identified session.

Comment: I don't really encounter the cookies dialog opening new chrome non-identified session. Can you help me with a snapshot please?

Comment: Ok, I've edited the post mentioning you, I added a picture. That box includes all.

Comment: Seems non English text. Can you update the question with the HTML of the **ACCETTO** button?

Comment: Ok, I-ve then uploaded an english-text screen

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to *delete* the ***cookie consent popup*** and can simply click on <kbd>I AGREE</kbd>.

---

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tp-yt-paper-button[aria-label='Agree to the use of cookies and other data for the purposes described'] yt-formatted-string.style-scope.ytd-button-renderer.style-primary.size-default#text"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//tp-yt-paper-button[@aria-label='Agree to the use of cookies and other data for the purposes described']//yt-formatted-string[@class='style-scope ytd-button-renderer style-primary size-default' and text()='I Agree']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Did either of the solution work for you?

Comment: Here's the string error.        
```
File "C:\Users\highm\Desktop\PYTHON FILES\Searchmemes\searchmemes.py", line 13, in <module>
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(., 'I AGREE')]"))).click()
  File "C:\Users\highm\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 89, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
```

Comment: Try the second option.

Comment: Ok, another type of error: "selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable: element has zero size"

Comment: Hmmm, for any further suggestion I'd need to see the text based HTML of the element. Can you update the question please?

Comment: Ok, I've uploaded the button HTML. If You were talking about something else, tell me.

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: It worked! I've used the CSS Selector method. Thank You for this much support!