# ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable error sending text to Account Name field within modal dialog using Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, modal-dialog, webdriverwait, expected-condition

I want to write function which click the button then type account and submit. But the program always stop after clicked at first button, but when I look at the driver, the pop up after click button is already appear.
Here is my code:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
print("click add account")
driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,
                    value='//*[contains(text(), "Add Account")]').click()
print("Type account...")
driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value='inp-address').send_keys(i)
time.sleep(1)
driver.execute_script("addAccount()")
```

This is the HTML of the first Button

```
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#modal-add-account">Add Account</button>
```

pop up after click appear:

[image: pop up after click appear]

Still has error:

[image: Still has error]

Comment: can you share the URL so we can help you more efficiently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ***Account Name*** field is within a [Modal Dialog Box](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp).

---

### Solution

To send the desired text you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code Block:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "inp-address"))).send_keys(i)
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```