# Why is my Selenium window not working like my normal window?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-chromedriver, geckodriver

I am building an analysis bot for an [io game called diep.io](https://diep.io). I am attempting to open diep.io in Ubuntu, using Python. Using Selenium to open Firefox, but I have the same problem with Chrome as well.

The code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://diep.io')
input() # to prevent auto-closure
```

It seems really simple so I don't get what's going on. When I open the browser manually and navigate to [diep.io](https://diep.io) it works normally, but when I open it with Selenium it runs very slowly, and doesn't show the 'enter your name here' box.

To be clear, I have geckodriver installed correctly, and I'm pretty certain I have the most current version of Python, Selenium, and Firefox. Other webpages work well enough, though they are kinda slow as well.

I can show screenshots or log files if it's needed to diagnose the issue. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the website detects your bot, you can check the network tab after firing your bot; it also uses cloudflare's protection

Answer (score 0):

To send a text within the *`<input>`* field e.g. ***Doremon*** and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
  from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  s = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
  driver.get("https://diep.io/")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#textInput"))).send_keys("Doremon" +Keys.RETURN)
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: Doremon]