# How can I use selenium to click a button

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

HTML snapshot of website:

[image]

The button is the rebounds button on 'https://app.prizepicks.com/board'. I've tried using the copy xPath feature, but that does not work.

Comment: That site uses JS to render elements. Therefore, you have to wait until it finishes rendering to select elements.

Comment: Update the question with the text based HTML and your code trials.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to wait until the elements show up or use time.sleep()
2. Below xpath works for me

   rebounds_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(text(), "Rebounds")]')
   rebounds_btn.click()

Answer (score 0):

Try the below,

```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(), 'Rebounds')]"))).click()
```

do not forget to import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as ***Rebounds*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use the following solution:

```
driver.get("https://app.prizepicks.com/board")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Rebounds']"))).click()
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```