# Using selenium (Python) webdriver is unable to locate the text field. Throws up error for finding element by Class, Input Type

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

HTML Code for the text bar is the following :

```html
<input data-v-0401fc16="" type="text" placeholder="Choose company" class="search_in">
```

CSS for the bar is as follows, so I also tried to put in the [data-v-0401fc16] in order to get the element by class name.

```css
.search_in[data-v-0401fc16] {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 34px;
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: #003a5d;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

How do I get send keys to the bar, I am unable to do so using the following :

```py
search = driver.find_element_by_class_name("search_in[data-v-0401fc16]")
search.send_keys("123")
```

The error I get using this method is as follows. I am not able to get the textbar element and unable to input text in it.

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".search_in[data-v-0401fc16]"}

Comment: In your case, the class name is only `search_in`, not `search_in[data-v-0401fc16]`

Comment: @MaximeCharrière Tried with``` search_in ``` but still shows up error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to find elements in a page and Selenium only to get the page content.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

try:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
except WebDriverException as e:
    print(f"{type(e).__name__} : {e}")
    return 1

driver.get(URL)

content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")
matches = soup.findAll('input', attrs={'class': 'search_in'})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the below line of code to find a web element:

```
search = driver.find_element_by_class_name("search_in[data-v-0401fc16]")
```

specifically you are using a `class_name` with this value `search_in[data-v-0401fc16]`

Based on the html that you've shared,

```
<input data-v-0401fc16="" type="text" placeholder="Choose company" class="search_in">
```

Here

**input** -> is `tag name`

**data-v-0401fc16** -> `attribute name` that has value as `""`

**type** -> `attribute name` that has value as `text`

**placeholder** -> `attribute name` that has value as `Choose company`

**class** -> `attribute name` that has value as `search_in`

class name is just `search_in` not `search_in[data-v-0401fc16]` that's the reason you are getting `selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:`

**Solution:**

Change `class_name` to `css_selector`

```
search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.search_in[data-v-0401fc16]")
search.send_keys("123")
```

Note that  `.` is to represent `class`, and basic `CSS selector` follows the below syntax:

```
tag_name[attr_name = 'attr_value']
```

Answer (score 0):

[find_element_by_class_name()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.by.html#selenium.webdriver.common.by.By.CLASS_NAME) would accept a single classname as an argument. So you can't pass the attribute *`data-v-0401fc16`*.

Moreover the attribute *`data-v-0401fc16`* is a dynamic attribute and may change when you would access the application afresh.

---

### Solution

To send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.search_in[placeholder='Choose company']"))).send_keys("Sarvesh Sharma")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='search_in' and @placeholder='Choose company']"))).send_keys("Sarvesh Sharma")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```