# How to make Selenium send text within DeepL.com

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

Website: [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/translator)

XPath for original text to translate:

```
//textarea[contains(@class, 'lmt__source_textarea')]
```

Error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//textarea[contains(@class, 'lmt__source_textarea')]"}
```

I'm also passing cookies.

*Note*: XPath works in Chrome Dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a *character sequence* within the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
driver.get("https://www.deepl.com/translator")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.dl_cookieBanner--buttonClose"))).click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@aria-labelledby='translation-source-heading']"))).send_keys("Good Boy")
```

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: deepl]

Comment: Request is sent using [scrapy-selenium](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium "scrapy-selenium") package. My request: `SeleniumRequest(url="https://www.deepl.com/translator",
                              wait_time=10,
                              wait_until=EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.dl_cookieBanner--buttonClose")))`. I get `selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException`.

Comment: How is request from _Selenium_ and _scrapy-selenium_ treated differently?

Comment: This is how scrapy-selenium handles [request](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium/blob/2e557f6f2221f2609b5b6c6cf3b609a28387d918/scrapy_selenium/middlewares.py#L97) & [expected conditions](https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium/blob/2e557f6f2221f2609b5b6c6cf3b609a28387d918/scrapy_selenium/middlewares.py#L113).

Comment: I'm using docker python interpreter. Program is working properly in local environment *(even without using `WebDriverWait()`)*. My concern is with docker, it isn't able to locate XPath for original text to translate. Other sites *(e.g [DuckDuckGo](https://duckduckgo.com/ "DuckDuckGo"))* is working perfectly with docker python interpreter.

Comment: From your code trials it doesn't looks like either _request_ or _expected_conditions_ was a concern, but the _**xpath**_. Did you test the xpath?

Comment: XPath works in local python interpreter & Chrome Dev tools.

Comment: I'm not asking about your _xpath_, but the _**xpath**_ I suggested in my answer when implemented in your code.

Comment: Yes your xpath is working  in local python interpreter & Chrome Dev tools..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244511/discussion-between-anil-and-undetected-selenium).

Comment: _xpath is working in local python interpreter_: So as per your question, wasn't that the answer you were looking for?

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.