# How to send text into an address bar which has a data-dojo-attach-point attribute

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to enter text into an address bar using the following code in python:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="esri_dijit_Search_0_input"]').send_keys('text')
```

However, it does not register anything when running without debugging. Could you please provide any solutions on how to input text into an address bar with the following html?

```
<form data-dojo-attach-point="formNode">
        <input maxlength="128" autocomplete="off" type="text" tabindex="0" class="searchInput" value="" aria-haspopup="true" id="esri_dijit_Search_0_input" data-dojo-attach-point="inputNode" role="textbox" placeholder="Address or Grid Reference" title="Address or Grid Reference" style="width: 170px;">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried it but there this seems to make the 'send keys' function inoperable.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is a dynamic element, because all variables eg. Xpath, data-dojo-attach-point stay the same, no matter how many times I reload the page. Again there still seems to be the problem of the send_keys function at the end of the code not working - the text of the send_keys is black rather than orange from previous code I have written.

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a dynamic element, so ideally to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.searchInput[id^='esri_dijit_Search'][title='Address or Grid Reference']"))).send_keys("text")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='searchInput' and starts-with(@id, 'esri_dijit_Search')][@title='Address or Grid Reference']"))).send_keys("text")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```