# How to send text to an input element within a webpage using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm trying to learn selenium and I want to fill out a form and copying some tutorial . In this form there a text input with this code :

```
<input required="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="First Name" type="text" id="firstName" class=" mr-sm-2 form-control">
```

Following the tutorial this code should do it :

```
from selenium import webdriver as w
d=w.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\chromedriver.exe")
d.get("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form")
try :
    d.find_element_by_id('firstName').send_keys("TEST")
except:
    print('cant identify')

d.quit()
```

I think the problem is the find element syntax anyways what is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

d.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="firstName"]').send_keys("amine")
d.find_element("id","lastName").send_keys("wannes")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

To send a *character sequence* to the `<input>` field you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#firstName"))).send_keys("hamdi")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get('https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form')
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='firstName']"))).send_keys("hamdi")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: toolsQA]

Comment: i know i can use another solution but why does my code not work ?

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know if any further questions.

Comment: d.find_element_by_id('firstName').send_keys("TEST") why is this not working ? seems that ide does not recognize it

Comment: Reread the answer and the embedded links.

Comment: @hamdisalim Take a look at the source HTML for the page and it will become obvious why your code doesn't work: it's because the `input` which you're trying to locate doesn't exist. That `input` and the `form` element containing it are not present in the HTML when the page loads and your Selenium process starts interrogating the page. Those elements are created by JavaScript code _after_ the page has loaded, so you will need to wait around until they have appeared.

Comment: nope u are wrong the problem isnt there , i asked a dev for help he said the function i used dosent work anymore for new versions so i used this instead

Comment: d.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="firstName"]').send_keys("amine")