# How to insert a value in text box using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have the following HTML structure and I am trying to use Selenium to enter a value

```
<div class="form-group justify-content-center d-flex">
    <form id="main-form" class="form-inline" action="/pushData" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="bnePp0JmVaVYuaTIAfuVIGT2y7usVssX3vQrAGaz"> 
        <input type="text" id="input-url" class="url-input" name="url" placeholder="Paste URL to shorten">
        <button class="button main-btn main-btn_primary" id="button-submit">Cut</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is my code

```
driver.find_element_by_id("input-url").send_keys("test")
driver.find_element_by_id("button-submit").click()
```

I want to get this element and enter a value.

Answer (score 0):

Select element by id:

```
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id("input-url")
inputElement.send_keys('testing')
```

Now you can simulate hitting ENTER:

```
inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

or if it is a form you can submit:

```
inputElement.submit()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Selenium 4.3.0: Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_*
> are now removed (#10712)

The following code will work:

```
[..]
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
[..]
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'input-url'))).send_keys('test')
button_to_be_clicked = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'button-submit')
button_to_be_clicked.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* to the `<input>` element you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.url-input#input-url[name='url'][placeholder='Paste URL to shorten']").send_keys("Phonex")
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@class='url-input' and @id='input-url'][@name='url' and @placeholder='Paste URL to shorten']").send_keys("Phonex")
  ```

---

Ideally to send a *character sequence* to the `<input>` element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.url-input#input-url[name='url'][placeholder='Paste URL to shorten']"))).send_keys("Phonex")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='url-input' and @id='input-url'][@name='url' and @placeholder='Paste URL to shorten']"))).send_keys("Phonex")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```