# Tiktok: Selenium unable to find upload area

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, tiktok

As the title suggests, my bot is unable to find the [upload area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Biuy0.png) on the tiktok website.

```
driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com/upload/")
time.sleep(5)
upld = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='root']/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/button")
upld.send_keys(r"C:\Users\Marius\final.mp4")
```

The error I am getting while running the code is:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='root']/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/button"}
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.134)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x01155FD3+2187219]
        Ordinal0 [0x010EE6D1+1763025]
        Ordinal0 [0x01003E78+802424]
        Ordinal0 [0x01031C10+990224]
        Ordinal0 [0x01031EAB+990891]
        Ordinal0 [0x0105EC92+1174674]
        Ordinal0 [0x0104CBD4+1100756]
        Ordinal0 [0x0105CFC2+1167298]
        Ordinal0 [0x0104C9A6+1100198]
        Ordinal0 [0x01026F80+946048]
        Ordinal0 [0x01027E76+949878]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013F90C2+2721218]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x013EAAF0+2662384]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x011E137A+526458]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x011E0416+522518]
        Ordinal0 [0x010F4EAB+1789611]
        Ordinal0 [0x010F97A8+1808296]
        Ordinal0 [0x010F9895+1808533]
        Ordinal0 [0x011026C1+1844929]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7615FA29+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77847A9E+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77847A6E+238]
```

I've tried running the bot on my other device and it worked with no flaws, but it doesnt seem to work when I try it with selenium for some reason. The chrome version is the same on all devices and on selenium as well.

I've tried css-selector and class find methods, but they still return no result.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As the [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) worked on your other device presumably the locator is flawless but ideally to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='root']/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/button"))).send_keys("C:\Users\Marius\final.mp4")
```

- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I used the WebDriverWait function and switched to the desired iframe to get the desired results. P.S: The WebDriverWait function helped my code run much faster and smoother.

Comment: @mariusaf Glad to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# There is an iframe on the page...
iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

# Wait until page loads...
time.sleep(3)

# Select the input file and send the filename...
upload = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input[type="file"]')
video_path = 'C:/Users/my_video.mp4'
upload.send_keys(video_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the content you are looking for in within an IFrame, Selenium XPath searches, unlike Google Chrome's Dev Tool XPath seaches, will not go into the IFrame. For this reason, all you need to do is switch iFrames and the code should work as expected.

```py
iframe = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe')
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

> Note: WebDriverWait will do nothing to fix the problem as the page has already fully loaded.