# Selenium - only sometimes sends send_keys

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am attempting to make a script to log in to Facebook, navigate to a specific webpage through the search bar, and then click on the top result; however, the script does not always send keys in the search bar and instead fails. Any idea why this is happening?

Another difficulty I am having is finding the correct path to the top search result. I have tried many different By. functions such as tag name, class, and x path yet none seem to work. Would greatly appreciate some help.

```
from ast import Return
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Carson/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")


try:
    username = WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'email')))
    
    username.send_keys("username")

    password = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'pass')
    password.send_keys("password")

    try:
        driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "button").click()
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/label/input').click()

        #clicks the search key and searches by send_keys 
        search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/label/input')
        search.click()
        search.send_keys('The Village At Gracy Farms')
        search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
        print("nicee")
      
    except:
        print("failedddd")
        driver.quit(77)

except:
    print("failed")
    driver.quit(22)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The search box element on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/) homepage is a dynamic element, so ideally to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Search Facebook'][aria-label='Search Facebook'][aria-label='Search Facebook']"))).send_keys("The Village At Gracy Farms")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Search Facebook' and @aria-label='Search Facebook'][@aria-expanded='true']"))).send_keys("The Village At Gracy Farms")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```