# How to send text into a angular input field after switching tabs using Selenium Python

Tags: python, angular, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to input text into a Angular input field after switching tabs. I keep getting either:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

error or

```
ElementClickInterceptedException
```

or

```
NoSuchElementException
```

I have also noticed that the `click()` command is no longer a method but say click: Any.

Below is the HTML for the input field I am trying to input text into:

```
<fieldset>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input ng-required="true" ng-readonly="!hasPriviledgeToEdit(user)" ng-model="user.loginId" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/" name="loginId" maxlength="16" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength" required="required">
    4-16 chars; A-z, 0-9, _
    <!-- ngIf: userProfileForm.loginId.$error.required --><span ng-if="userProfileForm.loginId.$error.required" class="invalid warning ng-scope">Required</span><!-- end ngIf: userProfileForm.loginId.$error.required -->
    <!-- ngIf: userProfileForm.loginId.$error.pattern -->
</fieldset>
```

Below is the code:

```
from multiprocessing.connection import wait
import time
from webbrowser import Chrome
from xml.etree.ElementPath import find

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://power.dat.com')

# chrome_optinons = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# chrome_optinons.add_argument('--headless')
# chrome_optinons.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')

#setup wait 
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

username = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mat-input-1"]')
username.send_keys('')

password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="mat-input-0"]')
password.send_keys('')


loginbutton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="submit-button"]')
loginbutton.click()

(time.sleep(5))

profiledrop = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="user-salutation"]')
profiledrop.click()

#store original window ID
original_window = driver.current_window_handle

#checks no other windows open
assert len(driver.window_handles) == 1


Adminbutton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#userPreferencesUl > li:nth-child(5) > a')
Adminbutton.click()


# driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])

#Wait for new window Tab
wait.until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))

#loops through till new window is confirmed open
for window_handle in driver.window_handles:
    if window_handle != original_window:
        driver.switch_to.window(window_handle)
        break

#Tells program to wait till new window confirmed 
wait.until(EC.title_is("Admin"))


NewUsrBtn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.newUser.ng-scope[ng-if^='isTrustedAdmin'][ng-click^='onNewUser']")))
NewUsrBtn.click()


UsrNM = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='loginId']")
UsrNM.send_keys('justin')
```

If you can explain how to get the proper Xpath for this element and if there is anything I need to do to make sure the driver continues to point to the new tab.

I have tried the below paths:

```
//input[@name='loginId']

input[name='loginId']

//*[@id="data"]/div[3]/table/tbody[1]/tr/td[1]/ng-form/fieldset[1]/input

#data > div.fixed-table-container-inner > table > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr > td:nth-child(1) > ng-form > fieldset:nth-child(1) > input
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As per the HTML:

```
<fieldset>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input ng-required="true" ng-readonly="!hasPriviledgeToEdit(user)" ng-model="user.loginId" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$/" name="loginId" maxlength="16" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength" required="required">
    4-16 chars; A-z, 0-9, _
    ...
</fieldset>
```

the element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, so ideally to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input.ng-pristine.ng-untouched.ng-invalid.ng-invalid-required.ng-valid-pattern.ng-valid-maxlength[name='loginId']"))).send_keys("DaHawg")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength' and @name='loginId']"))).send_keys("DaHawg")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thank you! Would you be able to explain how you got those paths? Havent been able to test it yet because I keep getting a ElementClickInterceptedException  error on the button click before that. Trying to figure out what is causing that.

Comment: Let's discuss the issue in [Selenium](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223360/selenium) room.

Comment: Says I dont have a high enough reputation to use the chat room :(

Comment: @DaHawg Sorry for that. I can explain but this won't be in context to the question at hand and won't be useful to the future visitors.

Comment: I understand I will try to get leveled up and reach out to you. Would you happen to have an idea why I would be getting a ElementClickInterceptedException error. NewUsrBtn in the code?

Comment: Are you facing `ElementClickInterceptedException` executing the code within my answer?

Comment: Kind of it is happening the line before your answer. But it is hit an miss. For example I just ran it and it added text no problem then ran it again with out changing anything and it threw the '''ElementClickInterceptedException'''

Comment: In short your previous lines of code are flaky. You should have asked that question in the first place. Anyway, I'm sure there are existing discussion based on Facebook login. Check those.

Comment: Thank you! I owe you big time. Once I get enough cred I will reach out to you in chat. Also when payday comes around I am going to send you some money to by a beer!