# StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page error on selecting option from Angular dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, html-select

I am trying to select an option from the drop down menu using selenium python depending on the value evaluated by the below line of code

```
elem = driver.find_element('xpath','xpath_value')
select = Select(driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="qty"]'))
select.select_by_visible_text(elem.text)  # value of elem.text = 1
```

The HTML code for the drop down menu is as per below

```
<select ng-disabled="c.data.product.limitPartsQuantity" ng-if="part.dist_channel_status_msg == 'Orderable' &amp;&amp; !c.data.isLightUser &amp;&amp; part.orderable &amp;&amp; !part.part_error" id="qty" name="qty" ng-model="part.quantity" ng-change="c.partSelected(part)" class="ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" style=""> <option value="0">0</option> <option value="1">1</option> <option value="2">2</option> <option value="3">3</option> <option value="4">4</option> <option value="5">5</option> <option value="6">6</option> <option value="7">7</option> <option value="8">8</option> <option value="9">9</option> <option value="10">10</option> <!-- ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --><option ng-if="c.data.type=='trade' &amp;&amp; c.pcf==false" value="15" class="ng-scope" style="">15</option><!-- end ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --> <!-- ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --><option ng-if="c.data.type=='trade' &amp;&amp; c.pcf==false" value="20" class="ng-scope">20</option><!-- end ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --> <!-- ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --><option ng-if="c.data.type=='trade' &amp;&amp; c.pcf==false" value="25" class="ng-scope">25</option><!-- end ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --> <!-- ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --><option ng-if="c.data.type=='trade' &amp;&amp; c.pcf==false" value="30" class="ng-scope">30</option><!-- end ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --> <!-- ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --><option ng-if="c.data.type=='trade' &amp;&amp; c.pcf==false" value="50" class="ng-scope">50</option><!-- end ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --> <!-- ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --><option ng-if="c.data.type=='trade' &amp;&amp; c.pcf==false" value="75" class="ng-scope">75</option><!-- end ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --> <!-- ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --><option ng-if="c.data.type=='trade' &amp;&amp; c.pcf==false" value="100" class="ng-scope">100</option><!-- end ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --> </select>
```

But when the code is run , the following error is generated

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

I can resolve the error by modifying the code as per below

```
elem = driver.find_element('xpath','xpath_value')
value = elem.text            # value = 1
select = Select(driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="qty"]'))
select.select_by_visible_text(value)
```

I would like to know why the first lines of code failed but the second works , even though they are basically the same expression .

Comment: Can you confirm the url, is it publicly accessible?

Comment: This happens because between the multiple round trips to the browser context and back... The DOM has changed. It's pretty common and you should consider switching to css_selector since xpath is relatively slow.

Comment: @Abhishek which `<option>` are you trying to select?

Comment: @platipus_on_fire No , the URL is private .

Comment: @pguardiario Thanks a lot . I got the logic after reading your comment.

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Option with value of 1 .

Answer (score -1):

From the HTML you have provided:

```
<select ng-disabled="c.data.product.limitPartsQuantity" ng-if="part.dist_channel_status_msg == 'Orderable' &amp;&amp; !c.data.isLightUser &amp;&amp; part.orderable &amp;&amp; !part.part_error" id="qty" name="qty" ng-model="part.quantity" ng-change="c.partSelected(part)" class="ng-valid ng-scope ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-touched" style=""> 
    <option value="0">0</option> 
    <option value="1">1</option> 
    <option value="2">2</option> 
    ...  
    ... 
    ...  
    <option value="10">10</option> 
    <!-- ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false -->
    <option ng-if="c.data.type=='trade' &amp;&amp; c.pcf==false" value="15" class="ng-scope" style="">15</option>
    <!-- end ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --> 
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <option ng-if="c.data.type=='trade' &amp;&amp; c.pcf==false" value="100" class="ng-scope">100</option>
    <!-- end ngIf: c.data.type=='trade' && c.pcf==false --> 
</select>
```

it is quite evident that the [html-select](/questions/tagged/html-select) element and it's decendant *`<option>`* elements are [Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241154/7429447) elements.

---

### Solution

To select the `<option>` with text as ***1*** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR* and *`select_by_value()`*:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "select#qty[name='qty'][ng-model$='quantity'][ng-change*='partSelected']")))).select_by_value('1')
  ```
- Using *XPATH* and *`select_by_visible_text()`*:

  ```
  Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='qty' and @name='qty'][contains(@ng-model, 'quantity') and contains(@ng-change, 'partSelected')]")))).select_by_visible_text('1')
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```