# How to click on the checkbox in reference to the text using Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm trying to access a checkbox which is contained within an element as shown below.

[image]

I cannot identify using xpath as the order of these elements can change during development. Id is also out of bounds because the developer has implemented a plain ascending order for id like item-0, item-1 etc, meaning, the id would change depending on the order of elements on the page. So I'd like to identify the text **Flexibel** and using this element tick the associated checkbox. Is there a way to do that?

The element hierarchy upon inspection is given below

```
<div _ngcontent-adp-c61="" class="col-xl-4 col-sm-6 py-2 ng-star-inserted" id="item-6">
 <div _ngcontent-adp-c61="" class="card border shadow-none h-100 mb-2">
  <input _ngcontent-adp-c61="" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input item-selector m-1 font-size-20 ng-star-inserted" style="z-index: 2;">
  <!---->
  <div _ngcontent-adp-c61="" class="card-body d-flex flex-column parent list-group-item-action pb-0" style="cursor: pointer;">
   <div _ngcontent-adp-c61="" class="d-flex align-items-start position-relative">
    <div _ngcontent-adp-c61="" class="flex-shrink-0 avatar rounded-circle me-3 ng-star-inserted"><img _ngcontent-adp-c61="" alt="" class="img-fluid border border-primary border-2 rounded-3" style="padding: 1px;" src="assets/ces/time-model/TimeModelType-TimeInterval.svg">
     <div _ngcontent-adp-c61="" class="d-flex justify-content-center">
      <!---->
     </div>
    </div>
   <!---->
   <div _ngcontent-adp-c61="" class="flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
    <div _ngcontent-adp-c61="" class="d-flex gap-2"><h5 _ngcontent-adp-c61="" class="font-size-15 mb-0 text-truncate"><span _ngcontent-adp-c61="" class="text-dark">Flexibel</span></h5><!---->
    </div>
    <p _ngcontent-adp-c61="" class="text-muted text-wrap mb-0 ng-star-inserted">allowed working hours for PQS team members</p>
    <!---->
   </div>
  </div>
  <div _ngcontent-adp-c61="" class="d-flex h-100 visible-parent-hover ng-star-inserted"><div _ngcontent-adp-c61="" class="btn flex-grow-1 align-self-end"><i _ngcontent-adp-c61="" class="uil-pen ng-star-inserted"></i><!----> Bearbeiten </div></div>
   <!---->
  </div>
  <!---->
 </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you confirm the url, is it publicly accessible?

Comment: Show how you tried

Comment: @platipus_on_fire the website is still in development so I'm unable to share it here

Comment: I didn't get far @Curiouskoala. What I tried to do is this `flex_elem = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'col-xl-4 col-sm-6 py-2 ng-star-inserted')`. With this I identified the entire element. Now, i can put in an if condition and say if this element contains the text 'Flexibel', click on the checkbox. But, I don't know how to get this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241154/7429447) element, so to click on the [checkbox](/questions/tagged/checkbox) element with respect to the text ***Flexibel***  you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *XPATH* and *`ancestor`*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='text-dark' and text()='Flexibel']//ancestor::div[contains(@class, 'card border shadow-none')]//input"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot @undetected Selenium, it worked! I had to spend some time learning about angular and the available contains() methods of selenium like parent, sibling, ancestor etc but I have a much clearer picture now. Cheers!

Comment: Glad to be able to help you.