# selenium cannot find element by xpath even though the xpath is correct

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

on this website https://www.firstbankcard.com/lynx/#/pre-qual/intake?agent=H48&sub=000 i am trying to send keys to the first name field using this code

```
driver5 = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
driver5.get('https://www.firstbankcard.com/lynx/#/pre-qual/intake?agent=H48&sub=000')
#fnbo first name
fnbofname = driver5.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="firstName"]')
fnbofname.send_keys(fname)
```

but i instead get this error returned

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="firstName"]"}

i did notice there was a couple iframes on the site but i dont know if they would affect my code hence why i am asking here if anyone can give me pointers/ examples as i feel like i keep running into what i think are problems cause by iframes but i dont know how to deal with them since they are not directly in the html text i am trying to copy

Comment: you may need time for the page to load (you could do time.sleep(5) as a simple test)

Comment: @AndrewRyan time.sleep was indeed the solution to my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is a [Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241154/7429447) element, so ideally to send a *character sequence* to the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.firstbankcard.com/lynx/#/pre-qual/intake?agent=H48&sub=000")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#firstName"))).send_keys("thrvxx")
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.firstbankcard.com/lynx/#/pre-qual/intake?agent=H48&sub=000")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='firstName']"))).send_keys("thrvxx")
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser snapshot:

[image: lynx]