# Unable to get attribute text from "list-item-value ng-binding" class - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

I have a Selenium script where I am trying to get the "list-item-value ng-binding" class from the Last Manual Run from the following:

```
  <div class="krn-modal-window">
<!-- ngIf: popupContentOptions.headerCancelButton.showButton --><button ng-disabled="popupContentOptions.headerCancelButton.action.disabled" class="jqx-window-close-button jqx-window-close-button-bluefin jqx-icon-close jqx-icon-close-bluefin ng-scope" ng-click="handleAction(popupContentOptions.headerCancelButton.action.clickHandlerName, popupContentOptions.headerCancelButton.action.actionName);" ng-if="popupContentOptions.headerCancelButton.showButton" autofocus=""></button>
<!-- end ngIf: popupContentOptions.headerCancelButton.showButton -->
<!-- ngIf: popupContentOptions.showHeader -->
<div class="modal-window__header ng-scope" ng-if="popupContentOptions.showHeader">
    <h4 ng-show="popupContentOptions.title.text" ng-bind="popupContentOptions.title.text | i18n" title="[undefined]" class="ng-binding ng-hide">[undefined]</h4>
    <h4 ng-show="popupContentOptions.title.localizedText" ng-bind="popupContentOptions.title.localizedText" title="Shift Builder" class="ng-binding">Shift Builder</h4>
</div>
<!-- end ngIf: popupContentOptions.showHeader -->
<div class="modal-window__body ng-scope">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li><b ng-bind="::'html.eventManager.properties.jobId'| i18n" class="list-item-label ng-binding">Job ID</b>:
            <div ng-bind="::modal.properties.jobId" class="list-item-value ng-binding">209</div>
        </li>
        <li><b ng-bind="::'html.eventManager.properties.lastRun'| i18n" class="list-item-label ng-binding">Last run</b>:
            <div ng-bind="::modal.properties.lastRun" class="list-item-value ng-binding"></div>
        </li>
        <li><b ng-bind="::'html.eventManager.properties.nextRun'| i18n" class="list-item-label ng-binding">Next run</b>:
            <div ng-bind="::modal.properties.nextRun" class="list-item-value ng-binding">25/06/2023 1:27</div>
        </li>
        <li><b ng-bind="::'html.eventManager.properties.modifiedBy'| i18n" class="list-item-label ng-binding">Modified By</b>:
            <div ng-bind="::modal.properties.modifiedBy" class="list-item-value ng-binding">Updater for 209</div>
        </li>
        <li><b ng-bind="::'html.eventManager.properties.modifiedDate'| i18n" class="list-item-label ng-binding">Modified Date</b>:
            <div ng-bind="::modal.properties.modifiedDate" class="list-item-value ng-binding">15/03/2010 12:35</div>
        </li>
        <li><b ng-bind="::'html.eventManager.properties.lastManualRun'| i18n" class="list-item-label ng-binding">Last Manual Run</b>:
            <div ng-bind="::modal.properties.lastManualRun" class="list-item-value ng-binding">19/06/2023 11:45</div>
        </li>
        <li><b ng-bind="::'html.eventManager.properties.errorText'| i18n" class="list-item-label ng-binding">Error text</b>:
            <div ng-bind="::modal.properties.errorText" class="list-item-value ng-binding"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I've tried to use the list and loop through to list the values but it doesn't seem to like finding the elements within the

tags.

Any ideas as I've not really got much experience dealing with these types of tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below XPath expression:

```
//b[text()='Last Manual Run']//following::div[1]
```

Example code:

```
String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//b[text()='Last Manual Run']//following::div[1]")).getText();
System.out.println(text);
```

Output:

```
19/06/2023 11:45
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the HTML:

```
<div class="modal-window__body ng-scope">
    <ul class="list-group">
    ...
    ...
    ...
    <li><b ng-bind="::'html.eventManager.properties.modifiedDate'| i18n" class="list-item-label ng-binding">Modified Date</b>:
        <div ng-bind="::modal.properties.modifiedDate" class="list-item-value ng-binding">15/03/2010 12:35</div>
    </li>
    <li><b ng-bind="::'html.eventManager.properties.lastManualRun'| i18n" class="list-item-label ng-binding">Last Manual Run</b>:
        <div ng-bind="::modal.properties.lastManualRun" class="list-item-value ng-binding">19/06/2023 11:45</div>
    </li>
    <li><b ng-bind="::'html.eventManager.properties.errorText'| i18n" class="list-item-label ng-binding">Error text</b>:
        <div ng-bind="::modal.properties.errorText" class="list-item-value ng-binding"></div>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The desired `<div>` tag is the sibling of the `<b>` tag containing the text ***Last Manual Run*** and is an [Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241154/7429447) element.

---

### Solution

To extract the text ***19/06/2023 11:45*** ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48990165/7429447) for the [*visibilityOfElementLocated()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49749804/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *xpath* and *following*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//b[contains(., 'Last Manual Run')]//following::div[1]"))).getText());
  ```
- Using *xpath* and *following-sibling*:

  ```
  System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//b[contains(., 'Last Manual Run')]//following-sibling::div[1]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
  ```