# ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point error clicking on Search button using Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I want to webscrape the following website:
https://sprs.parl.gov.sg/search/home

But when my code clicks on the "Search button", I get the error:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (320, 1395)
```

I am not sure if it's because the ***Search button*** is not completely visible and needs scrolling down. If so, how do I scroll down the page using Selenium?

Code trials:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs 
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/chromedriver.exe")
page_url = 'https://sprs.parl.gov.sg/search/home'
driver.get(page_url)
# Get search box and fill it up
search = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#divmpscreen2 > div.row > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(1) > input')
search.send_keys('COS')
# This will select the 13th parliament
session = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select/option[contains(text(), '13th')]")
session.click()
time.sleep(10)
# Find submit element and click
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@label='Search']/em")
submit.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the <kbd>Search</kbd> button you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65141861/7429447) and you can use the following [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

```
driver.get('https://sprs.parl.gov.sg/search/home')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#divmpscreen2 > div.row > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(1) > input"))).send_keys('COS')
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//label[text()='By Parliament']//following-sibling::select[1]")))).select_by_value('13: 13')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-black' and @label='Search']/em"))))
```

Browser Snapshot:

[image: SearchResults]

**Note**: You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: I am referring to the "Search" button at the bottom right of the page, not the search by key words

Comment: Checkout the updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: Used
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit)

Comment: Even you can do that, but as the desired element is an angular element ideally you should use WebDriverWait before any interaction.

Answer (score 2):

We can try click by using moving to element or by using java script executor

```
Actions action = new Actions(webdriver);
WebElement we = webdriver.findElement(By.xpath("path here"));
action.moveToElement(we).click().build().perform();
```

using javascript

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfd"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you suppose to click an element using Selenium:

```
def clickLastFoundElement(my_element):       
    try:
        builder = Actions(browser)
        builder.moveToElement(my_element).click().build().perform()
    except ElementNotInteractableException:
        try:
            my_element.click()          
        except Exception:
            hardClickElement(my_element)

def hardClickElement(element):
    executor = (JavascriptExecutor)browser
    executor.executeScript('arguments[0].click();', element)
```

Sometimes an element won't be clicked, and you will have to "hard" click it by injecting JavaScript code into it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't understand your code. What is element and my_element? Is there extra library I need to import?

Comment: @123456 my_element is the problematic element giving you the error. The word element is a parameter, you need to pass the method hardClickElement my_element

Comment: I added to my code but get "Invalid Syntax" Error. Also is browser=driver.get(page_url)? Thanks!

Comment: @123456 Yes, browser=driver.get(page_url). What invalid syntax you got?

Comment: This is not valid python syntax. You need `def` before any method declaration. You've also referenced `my_element` in `clickLastFoundElement()` but haven't declared it or added it as a parameter. Also, there's no such thing as a "hard click". It's just a JS click... and these should be avoided whenever possible because you are bypassing any validation, etc. that the webpage has around the element you are interacting with. No user can JS click an element. Best practice is to not use them.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to select the desired info and click that button (EDIT: a better way without ActionChains, and working on smaller sized windows as well):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time as t


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://sprs.parl.gov.sg/search/home'

browser.get(url) 
searchbox = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[contains(text(), 'By Keyword')]/following-sibling::input")))
print(searchbox.location_once_scrolled_into_view)
searchbox.send_keys('COS')
govt_nr = Select(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[contains(text(), 'By Parliament')]/following-sibling::select"))))
govt_nr.select_by_index(13) 
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
t.sleep(1)
submit_button = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[label = 'Search']")))
submit_button.click()
```

Setup is linux/chromedriver, you just have to observe the imports, and the code after defining the browser/driver.

Selenium docs: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

One more thing to keep in mind: results will open in a new tab, so you will need to switch to it using something to the tune of `switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])`.