# A button at webpage and i want to pass it by click or anything but nothing works . is there another way?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
import selenium
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

the button ("< a class="entity__btn-next" href="#/account">Next**strong text**" )

```
 try :
             
             driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div/div/section[2]/div[1]/div/div/a').click()
      
       except : 
            print('1')
            pass
       
      
       
       sleep(1)
       try :

             driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'#container > div > div > section.sign-up__content > div.next-card.next-card-free.next-card-show-divider.content__card > div > div > a').click()
     
       except : 
            print('2')
            pass
       
       sleep(1)
       try :
             driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT,'Next').click()
      
       except : 
            print('3')
            pass
       
       sleep(1)
       try :
             driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'entity__btn-next').click()
       
       except : 
            print('4')
            pass
    

       sleep(1)
       try :
             driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,'Next').click()
       
       except : 
            print('5')
            pass



    
       sleep(1)
       try :
             driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'a').click()
       
       except : 
            print('6')
            pass
```

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: if driver click is not working as expected, we can use click by using javascript executor. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73525437/elementclickinterceptedexception-element-click-intercepted-element-is-not-clic/73526064#73526064

Comment: @murali selenium
every try of them is excption .

Comment: can you confirm the url of the page?

Comment: https://account.alibabacloud.com/register/intl_register.htm?spm=a2c45.11132017.2.2.5bf279f4gaKeOm&lang=en_US&oauth_callback=

Comment: You've stated your question in the title. Restate it in the actual question block, and then give some context to the code blocks you're posting.